# How can I get top 5 names with their working hours, who worked the most using pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*I want to individuality print top each names with their working hours one by one.*

pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['Joesph Morse', 'Katie Plotkin', 'Denny Heaps', 'Evelia Chesson', 'Drew Hassett', 'Robt Buckles', 'Suzy Lafler'], 'CITY': ["New York", "Boston", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Atlanta",
    "Salt Lake City", "Dallas"], 'WORK HOURS': [3, 7, 0, 6, 10, 1, 9]}
)
```

Currently I'm targeting `"Work Hours"` column, with nlargest that filters top big numbers from the row, but It do not help me to get name of the worker along with their work hours. How can I get their names too?

```
row = df['WORK HOURS']
leading_workers =  row.nlargest(5, 'all')

print('Top First worker',leading_workers.values[0]) # user_1
print('Top Second worker',leading_workers.values[1]) # user_2
print('Top Third worker',leading_workers.values[2]) # user_3
print('Top Forth worker',leading_workers.values[3]) # user_4
print('Top Fifth worker',leading_workers.values[4]) # user_5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) with specify column names for test and select `NAME` for `leading_workers`:

```
leading_workers = df.nlargest(5, 'WORK HOURS', 'all')['NAME']

print (leading_workers)
4      Drew Hassett
6       Suzy Lafler
1     Katie Plotkin
3    Evelia Chesson
0      Joesph Morse
Name: NAME, dtype: object

for w in leading_workers:
    print (w)
Drew Hassett
Suzy Lafler
Katie Plotkin
Evelia Chesson
Joesph Morse
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['Joesph Morse', 'Katie Plotkin', 'Denny Heaps',
    'Evelia Chesson', 'Drew Hassett', 'Robt Buckles', 'Suzy Lafler'],

'CITY': ["New York", "Boston", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Atlanta",
    "Salt Lake City", "Dallas"],

'WORK HOURS': [3, 7, 0, 6, 10, 1, 9]}
)

df.sort_values(by='WORK HOURS',ascending=False,inplace=True)
```

Is another way to do it, with the output

```
    NAME            CITY            WORK HOURS
4   Drew Hassett    Atlanta         10
6   Suzy Lafler     Dallas          9
1   Katie Plotkin   Boston          7
3   Evelia Chesson  Chicago         6
0   Joesph Morse    New York        3
5   Robt Buckles    Salt Lake City  1
2   Denny Heaps     Los Angeles     0
```

and if you want the first 5 rows

```
df.head(5)

    NAME            CITY            WORK HOURS
4   Drew Hassett    Atlanta         10
6   Suzy Lafler     Dallas          9
1   Katie Plotkin   Boston          7
3   Evelia Chesson  Chicago         6
0   Joesph Morse    New York        3
```

Comment: `df.head()` already returns the first 5 rows, there is no need to specify the number